# Relative date range in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to select for all items where the createDt is in the last two weeks.  I've tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable
WHERE CreateDt > dateadd(d,-15,CreateDt)
```

Can someone tell me the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how it doesn't work?  Also, why are you using 15 instead of 14 days?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
WHERE CreateDt > dateadd(d,-15,CreateDt)
```

should be

```
WHERE CreateDt > dateadd(d,-15,getdate())
```

Presumably.

All `NOT NULL` values of `CreateDt` will meet your current condition as you are comparing the column with its own value minus 15 days - not 15 days previous to the current date and time.

Answer (score 2):

"Where createdate > (createdate - 2 weeks)"?  I don't think so ;)

Try this:

```
... where createdate > dateadd (d, -15, getdate())
```

Answer (score 2):

You're checking to see if CreateDt is Greater than 15 days prior to itself.  I'm guessing you're getting a lot more records than you expect.

I would do something like this (for readability, primarily)

```
Declare @CheckDate DateTime
Set @CheckDate = dateadd(d, -15, GetDate())

SELECT [Columns] from dbo.mytable WHERE CreateDt > @CheckDate
```

Also- remember to call out your columns- don't use "SELECT *" in normal circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you want.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable
WHERE CreateDt > dateadd(wk,-2,getdate()) AND
      CreateDt < getdate() -- possible bad data
```